# explain what is missing from 10print

Tags: basic, c64

10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND+(1));:GOTO 10
I seem to be the only person ever to not be able to do this. i have written all kinds of BASIC but I can't do anything with this. What am i missing?
I get "SYNTAX ERROR IN 10"
i  can't get it to work And really, why would it? 205 is a memory address and so   the value of 5 in and we have random number thing going but where does the pattern come from. Don't we need? "/" "\ ".
205.5 produces these/??? that doesn't make any sense. I must have an extreme misunderstanding of computers and BASIC that curiously doesn't prevent me from creating functioning programs.
I also program in C and I am still completely clueless. never seen anything like this work seems like there is a hidden line 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, that wasn't listed so I don't know what the rest of the code is???
I've tried on the 64mini and several emulators and they all give the same error.
Did I have a stroke and need to goto the hospital? maybe I can no longer discern what I see on the screen Lol.

10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND+(1));:GOTO 10

Comment: That should be `RND(1)`, not `RND+(1)`.

Comment: For some reason people like suggesting books you can read on topics, so let's do that: [book](https://10print.org/)

Answer (score 5):

As [pointed out by teapot418](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289842/explain-what-is-missing-from-10print#comment132854631_75289842), you have a typo in your code. The exact code is:

```
10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND(1)); : GOTO 10
```

`CHR$` creates the ASCII character for the given number. (What you wrote about reading from address is `PEEK`.)

`CHR$(205)` gives you the "\" and `CHR$(206)` the "/". The floating part of the number gets ignored. Because of the randomness, you get random sequences of `CHR$(205)` and `CHR$(206)` which creates the maze. The `;` at the end of `PRINT` avoids a newline.

Comment: One minor nitpick: It's PETSCII instead of ASII and the characters are more like `"╲"` and `"╱"` instead of `"\"` and `"/"`. PETSCII also has a `"/"` character (`CHR$(47)`). But no `"\"` — it's ASCII code is the british pound sign `"£"` in PETSCII.